# How can I get the day of the year in crystal reports?

Tags: crystal-reports

As an example, I think today, Dec 3 would be 337. Which crystal reports function will do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DateDiff( "d", Date(Year(CurrentDate), 01, 01),CurrentDate) + 1)

+1 Gives means that on Jan 1, it will give you 1 instead of 0.

Answer (score 1):

```
DateDiff("d",DateSerial (year(currentdate)-1, 12, 31),currentdate)
```

Using CR 8.5 I had to set the start date using the DateSerial function. I had the start date be Dec 31 of the previous year to get an accurate number for today's date.